# Mark a class as needing for disposal in Dart

Tags: dart

I was wondering if there's a way to mark a class as "needing disposal" in Dart.

What I mean to do is replicate the linter warning that gets shown, for example, when I create a `StreamController` and not dispose it somewhere in my code, the `close_sinks` warning is shown.

This does not happen for other classes like `AnimationController` or `ValueNotifier`.

What does make a class raise this kind of warning? How can I replicate that for my own needs? Can I at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no way, but you can follow the issue progress here: https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/697

Comment: oh I see, well thank you! I've subscribed to the issue, hoping for the best!